# Wasn’t this planet already back before The Magician's Apprentice?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, dalek

In *The Magician's Apprentice*, it is said that Skaro was destroyed or time locked and brought back. So how can the Matt Smith Doctor be there on Skaro in *Asylum of the Daleks*?

> [Planet surface]
>   MISSY: They've built it again. They've brought it back. No, no. No!
>   CLARA: What? What is it? Where are we?
>
> [Davros' room]
>   (The buildings are all visible from the window.)
>   DOCTOR: Skaro! You've brought me to Skaro.

<sup>([source](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-1.html))</sup>

Comment: Can you quote the specific line that you paraphrase as "Skaro was destroyed or time locked and brought back"? There's a transcript of the The Magician's Apprentice [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-1.html), and also one for The Witch's Familiar [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-2.html) in case you're remembering a line from part 2 of the story.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: I sorted it.

Answer (score 4):

In *Asylum of the Daleks*, the Doctor is on Skaro and Skaro is a pile of rubble. It's ruins.

By *The Magician's Apprentice*, Davros had brought the *city* back; i.e. rebuilt and repaired … and moved everyone back in.

**Missy didn't mean the planet had literally returned to physical existence.**

Indeed, it had always *existed*; it merely had the living crap beaten out of it "during" the Time War.